# Getting results of Protractor tests In Bamboo

Tags: selenium, protractor, mocha.js, bamboo

I am running protractor tests on a remote Selenium Server which works fine.

Next step is creating a build job on Bamboo for starting the tests on that remote server. The problem here is that **only the last test is shown in the results**

if these are my test files only the results of myThirdTestSpec.js are saved:

- myFirstTestSpec.js
- mySecondTestSpec.js
- myThirdTestSpec.js

Using the [mocha-bamboo-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-bamboo-reporter) I noticed that the results file (mocha.json) is being removed each time a Spec file is called. This explains why only the last one is visible in the results.

However when I run the tests on a local browser all test result are being saved correctly.

My guess is that with the remote selenium server **a new Mocha runner is started  each time a Spec file starts to execute**. So what happens is that the bamboo reporter cleans up old data before each runner. Am I right?
Any ideas on solving this issue?